# Ford ikon 1.8 nxt diesel - Starting problem

Tags: engine, ford, starting, diesel

Ford ikon 1.8 nxt diesel. It has coverd 130000 kms. Now in winter, there is starting trouble. Mostly it takes 30 to 35 secs. Long self. I have checked its heater , hetaer timer ,fuel leakage , battery replaced .but problem as it is.

Comment: Glow plugs are probably the issue. When they start going bad (or you get a couple of bad ones) it takes them longer to heat the chambers and this causes hard starting in your diesel.

Comment: I have checked manually  too.

Comment: @Mr.SINGH what did you check manually?

Comment: @Mr.SINGH How did you check the glow plugs ?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely your issues are related to old glow plugs.

Glow plug replacement is a standard maintenance task.

Your glow plugs in a diesel are the equivalent to spark plugs in a gasoline engine.

Comment: I overhauled engine . Problem solved.